# Не обновляется robots txt в url

Tags: robots.txt, sitemap

Всем привет. Отредактировал файл robots txt и sitemap, залил на сервер, но по url site.com.ua/robots.txt и site.com.ua/sitemap.xml выводятся старые данные до обновления. Чистил весь возможный кеш, но не помогло. Кто сталкивался, как можно обновить?
Сайт написан на symfony. Почистил кеш на сервере командой php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod и в браузере. На сервере файлы с обновленными данными но по url старые все равно. И google видит только старый вариант. Может еще какой кеш надо почистить?

Comment: В вопросе слишком мало информации, чтобы быть уверенным, что вы реально почистили кеши. Может быть что-то пропустили -- такие ошибки по невнимательности бывают. Либо не очень хорошо знаете как устроен движок вашего сайта.Также рекомендую проверить открыв сайт в приватной вкладке или в браузере, в котором ещё не смотрели сайт.

Comment: Может, вы их залили вообще не туда? Информации слишком мало всё равно